# Storing class files in dll and using the dll for multiple websites in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, code-reuse

I want to create a class file in VS2005 and be able to use it in other websites on my computer / production server. How do I create this dll and store it in a common place where I can reference it while developing and also on the production server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a class library project to your solution. Add this class into this library. And deploy this class to Global Assembly Cache (GAC). You can follow [these steps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315682) to install your assembly to GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the GAC unless you have full administration rights on the host server.

What you could do is create a project containing the source for your shared DLL. You can then add this project into each of your web site solutions, and add a reference in your site solutions to the project. This has the added advantage of enabling you to step into your shared source during debugging.